# HTML - How to do a square plain button while using jQuery Mobile css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing using jQuery-Mobile, and I want to develop a square button.

For that, what I did was modify it's height with css, and since I cannot modify it's width, I just wrote some random text in it so it became square.

This button is going to be changing it's background color depending on user interaction, so I tried changing at the same time the color text and background color so the text would "disappear".

But this is what happens:

[image][image]

As you can see, the text (mmmmmm) is visible, so:

How can I make the text to be transparent?

**EDIT:**

This is the code:

```
<button id="btn1" data-inline="true">mmmmm</button>
```

And this is the css preventing me from modifying the width:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jqueryMobile/jquery-1.11.0.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"/></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="personal.css" />
```

And the only code in `personal.css`

```
.ui-btn {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you modify its width?

Comment: `display: block;` and you can edit its width and height and remove the text.

Comment: &nbsp; can use for empty space. But why can't you set the width?

Comment: I think this is preventing it: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />` When I take it out I can modify it's width

Comment: Put your CSS after that library is included, css stands for Cascading Style Sheet Look it up

Comment: Ok, I just ended deleting that css, it's a shame I have to loose the look of jQuery Mobile. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Try adding !important to your width declaration, this is not good practice but it'll force it to ignore other width declarations on that element. Like this: width: 220px !important;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove text's shadow.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4r6tr503/).

```css
text-shadow: none;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That's what those lines in the screenshot are, duh! dumb me. 
Also, nice nickname ;)

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I just had to do that and add `!important` and it worked! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height like you set the width:

```
.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If you still can't set the width because another css file is overriding it, try using the !important word. It's not good practice but it'll ignore other width declarations on that element:

```
.square {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use display:block?

Comment: Because I'm not really sure with "button" he means an actual <button> and not an <a> tag, and a tags are inline by default, not allowing to set the width. But he says he set its height so you're probably right, he's using a <button>

Comment: Yes, I'm using <button>

Comment: I edited the question so I give more info